# How to get html of a page with ajax in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

So far this is my code:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "/image/senran-kagura-estival-versus-2015-07-13-15-005-811425-264284",
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(data) {
         alert($(data).html()); // On passe code_html à jQuery() qui va nous créer l'arbre DOM !
     },
     error: function(resultat, statut, erreur) {},
     complete: function(resultat, statut) {}
 });
```

No matter what's the url it's always undefined as a result in the success method. I've tried alerting the `data` alone or `$(data)` or `data.contents` nothing works is either blank or undefined. Is something wrong with my ajax?

Comment: which data you returning from ajax call ? can you pls add in question?

Comment: @NishitMaheta  There's no data, i want the html of the page but nothing is returned in the data variable i don't know why. the request always goes in success

Comment: What happens when you go to the URL. did you check your URL is correct? also you dont need the dataType defined. if it is html the call will provide that to you.

Comment: alert(data); check it

Comment: what ever mention in file you call for ajax .. it will return all data contain in side file .  have you added any html code in side ajax file ?

Comment: @MukeshKalgude It's just blank, nothing in the alert. And if i do .html() it's undefined

Comment: @Qpirate yes i've chhecked the url works and it's the url i want to go

Comment: @Qpirate If i don't mention datatype it goes to error function

Comment: @user5014677 I think there is an issue with your relative path. What happens when you provide an absolute path?

Comment: @ramesh same thing i just tried

Comment: is there anyway you could put the code on a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You have called complete, so you can check your response in complete action. I have **console log** the response
I have also update `dataType: 'text/html',`

Please check the example :

```js
$.ajax({
     url: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js",
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'text/html',
     success: function(data) {
         alert(data); // On passe code_html à jQuery() qui va nous créer l'arbre DOM !
     },
     error: function(resultat, statut, erreur) {},
     complete: function(resultat, statut) {
       console.log(resultat);
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This return a [Object object]

Comment: yes, you can get data using like : console.log(resultat.name) OR console.log(resultat[0].name)

Comment: .name? I want div#something how do i do that with this? ^^'

Comment: can you post your response... so that get more idea about how to get it

Comment: I just want the html code so i can search for a a pricular id and get its info

Comment: for that you can use $('div#someID').find('element');

Comment: man, i want it from another page, i'm on main page and i want to get a div from another page on the same domain. I'm using ajax for that but apparently ajax doesn't want to work

Comment: can you give full url of page from where you want to get data ?

Comment: http://www.gamergen.com/actualites/senran-kagura-estival-versus-premieres-images-ayame-combattante-264284-1

Comment: My query is executed on the same domain from the main page

Comment: run on chrome and check console.log(resultat). still the same [Object object]

Answer (score 0):

You should try data.d.html() as it is simply a security feature that Microsoft added in ASP.NET 3.5’s version of ASP.NET AJAX. By encapsulating the JSON response within a parent object (d).